# Minor tweak needed

Tags: php

I've a system that I need to get a minor tweak made to and hope someone can advise.I've a custom field from a modal called 'cancle_order_reason' that needs to be added to a transactions table when a internal refund is made. Currently the table says just 'internal', but I want it to give the info from the 'cancle_order_reason' field for greater info.

From what I can see the relevant controllers are
**packages/catalyst/controllers/dashboard/catalyst/orders.php** which is where the modal is.

```
public function add_refund_order(){
    $valt = Loader::helper('validation/token');
    if (!$valt->validate('add_refund_order', $this->post('token'))) {
        throw new Exception($valt->getErrorMessage());
    }

    Loader::model('proforms_item','proforms');
    $pfo = ProFormsItem::getByID($this->post('orderID'));
    $orderID = $this->request('orderID');
    $question_set = $pfo->asID;
    $setAttribs = AttributeSet::getByID($question_set)->getAttributeKeys();
    foreach ($setAttribs as $ak) {
        if($ak->getAttributeType()->getAttributeTypeHandle() == 'price_total'){
            $value = $pfo->getAttributeValueObject($ak);
            $db = Loader::db();
            $avID = $value->getAttributeValueID();
            
            $amount = money_format('%(#4n',$this->post('credit_amount'));
            
            $ak->getController()->savePayment($avID,$amount,2);
        }
    }
    
    $desc = trim($amount . ' ' . $this->request('cancle_order_reason'));
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $u = new User();
    
    $data = array(
        'ProformsItemID'=> $this->request('orderID'),
        'action'=> 'Refund (Internal)',
        'amount'=> $amount,
        'description'=> $desc,
        'uID'=> $u->uID,
        'date' => $date
    );
    
    Loader::model('order_history', 'catalyst');
    $oh = new OrderHistory();
    $oh->addOrderHistoryItem($data);
    
    $this->redirect('/dashboard/catalyst/orders/refund_added_order/?view_order='.$orderID);
}
```

and then the model controller:
**models/attribute/types/price_total/controller.php**

```
public function savePayment($avID=null, $amount, $credit=null, $transID='internal', $type='internal', $status=1){
    // $credit == 2 is refund
    $this->load();
    $db = Loader::db();
    if($this->getAttributeValueID()){
        $avID = $this->getAttributeValueID();
    }
    $db->Execute("INSERT INTO atPriceTotalPayments (avID,amount,payment_date,credit,transactionID,type,status) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", [$avID, $amount, date('Y-m-d'), $credit, $transID, $type, $status]);
    
    $this->updatePaidAmount($avID);
}
```

What is needed is for the details contained in field name ‘cancle_order_reason’ on the modal to be used in place of the ‘internal’ on $transID=‘internal’ on the models/attribute/types/price_total/controller.php. I’ve tested replacing ‘internal’  with some other text, and it updates, so it is the correct one to update.

I’ve tried:

```
$amount = money_format('%(#4n',$this->post('credit_amount')); 
$transID = $this->request('cancle_order_reason'); 
$ak->getController()->savePayment($avID,$amount,$transID);
```

And nothing changes.

Changing the other controller so

```
$transID='internal'
```

becomes

```
$transID
```

results in an error:

> Too few arguments to function
> PriceTotalAttributeTypeController::savePayment(), 3 passed in
> /home/bookinme/web/test.book-in.me/public_html/packages/catalyst/controllers/dashboard/catalyst/orders.php
> on line 842 and at least 4 expected.

Comment: You should be able to pass it as the fourth argument to your call to `savePayment()` within the `foreach` loop.

Comment: That's helpful. Are you able to suggest appropriate code? I'm between developers and it's become an urgent issue to try to resolve ;-)

Comment: @Justyn This site is for developers to help each other - and create a useful repository of useful questions to help other developers in future. Us giving you free code to do something standard like add a parameter to a function (and whatever else you're inevitably going to then ask us next) doesn't really achieve that goal. We're not here to provide you with free development resource because you haven't hired anyone yet. You can find freelancers on other sites. OTOH if you're familiar enough with the code to work out which files to post in your question, then you could probably try it yourself

Comment: I'm a learning developer. Know enough to edit and tweak.

Comment: To be more specific then: you can add the value of `$this->request('cancle_order_reason')` (assuming the definition of `$desc` is working correctly) as the fourth argument to the function call in the `$ak->getController()->savePayment($avID,$amount,2);` line of your `orders.php` file. No other changes are necessary.

Comment: I’ve tried:
    $amount = money_format('%(#4n',$this->post('credit_amount'));
                $transID = $this->request('cancle_order_reason');
    $ak->getController()->savePayment($avID,$amount,$transID);
And nothing changes. Changing the other controller so $transID='internal' becomes $transID results in an error: Too few arguments to function PriceTotalAttributeTypeController::savePayment(), 3 passed in /home/bookinme/web/test.book-in.me/public_html/packages/catalyst/controllers/dashboard/catalyst/orders.php on line 842 and at least 4 expected.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Thank for the help. I'd tried that but had been getting an error. I realised that for some reason of the variables was in the code I'd pasted, but not in the code in the system. That was throwing the error. I've corrected, and it now all works.